# How can I replace one or more instance of a specific character with a dash?

Tags: .net, regex, .net-4.0

I need help in writing a RegEx able to detect 1 or more instance of a defined characters in a string (in my example an empty space) and replace with a single DASH.

I'm using at the moment this RegEx, it replace one ore more instances of an Empty Space in a string.

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\s+", "-");
```

I would like have a similar approach but for another character example:
`;` or `&`.

Any idea how to solve it? Thansk for your time on this.

Comment: The `regex` tag is all that is needed to identify a questions as being about regular expressions. There's no need for tags in the title as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\s+|;+|&+", "-");
```

Comment: Hi what does it means the | (just after the +)?

Comment: @GibboK, thats the Pipe operator that means match `\s+` OR `;+` OR `&+`

Comment: It is a logical OR, just like `||` in C#. I chose this approach over the character class approach by stema as it allows you to also replace one or more instances of longer patterns, e.g. `Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\s+|(==)+", "-");` would replace one or multiple spaces with a single dash and one or multiple occurences of a double equation symbol with a single dash, but it would leave alone a single equation symbol.

Comment: That's true, if you want to have longer patterns to replace you would need the OR solution. Good, working (expandable) solution, so +1

Comment: Just last question how can I scape the character "  ?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\s+|;+|&+|""+", "-");`

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[;&]+", "-");
```

`[;&]` is a character class containing the characters inside the square brackets. You can add there all characters you want to have replaced.

If you want to combine with your working solution, just add `\s` to the class

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[\s;&]+", "-");
```

Comment: Just be careful with this solution as it will match mixed strings (`;&;`) as well as uniform ones (`;;;`), and this may not be what you want.

Comment: @Dan putting the patterns together using OR like this `@"\s+|;+|&+"` will replace exactly the same stuff. Its just matched differently.

Comment: `\s+|;+|&+` matches series of only one repeated character out of the three. Check the last line: http://regexr.com?2udr9 vs. http://regexr.com?2udrc If you were simply removing the matched characters, yes, they would work the same, but you need to be more careful when replacing the matches.

Comment: @Dan Now I see your point. Yes you are right it will result in different amount of dashes here, so depends what behaviour you want.

Comment: It's a little unclear if this is what was wanted or not, and it's a good solution as long as you understand the little difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just change \s to ; or & and it should work.